# File exists but showing no such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I am trying to perform a set of terminal operations using bash shell script. Below is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE_DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
ARCHIVE_DIR="/home/tanmay/backup/"
TAR_GZ=".tar.gz"
PATH=( "/home/tanmay/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/logs" "/home/tanmay/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/webapps" )
FOLDER=("logs" "webapps" )
for number in {0..1..1}
do
    echo ${PATH[number]}
    echo ${FOLDER[number]}
    rsync -vrzh ${PATH[number]} ${ARCHIVE_DIR}
    tar -zcvf ${ARCHIVE_DIR}/${FOLDER[number]}${TAR_GZ} ${ARCHIVE_DIR}/${FOLDER[number]}
    rm -rf ${ARCHIVE_DIR}/${FOLDER[number]}
    if [ -f ${ARCHIVE_DIR}/${FOLDER[number]}${TAR_GZ} ]
    then
        mv ${ARCHIVE_DIR}${FOLDER[number]}${TAR_GZ} ${ARCHIVE_DIR}${FOLDER[number]}_${FILE_DATE}${TAR_GZ}
    fi    
done
```

When I run this script, both the echo is showing the correct values. But operations (rsync,tar..) are returning file not found. Below is the output

```
/home/tanmay/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/logs
logs
./server_data_backup_updated.sh: line 11: rsync: No such file or directory
./server_data_backup_updated.sh: line 12: tar: No such file or directory
./server_data_backup_updated.sh: line 13: rm: No such file or directory
/home/tanmay/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/webapps
webapps
./server_data_backup_updated.sh: line 11: rsync: No such file or directory
./server_data_backup_updated.sh: line 12: tar: No such file or directory
./server_data_backup_updated.sh: line 13: rm: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE 1**

Using one array instead on two. It is working now.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE_DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
ARCHIVE_DIR="/home/tanmay/backup/"
TAR_GZ=".tar.gz"
array=( "/home/tanmay/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/logs" 
    "logs" 
    "/home/tanmay/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/webapps" 
    "webapps")

for number in {0..2..2}
do
    rsync -vrzh ${array[number]} ${ARCHIVE_DIR}
    tar -zcvf ${ARCHIVE_DIR}/${array[number+1]}${TAR_GZ} ${ARCHIVE_DIR}/${array[number+1]}
    rm -rf ${ARCHIVE_DIR}/${array[number+1]}
    if [ -f ${ARCHIVE_DIR}/${array[number+1]}${TAR_GZ} ]
    then
        mv ${ARCHIVE_DIR}${array[number+1]}${TAR_GZ} ${ARCHIVE_DIR}${array[number+1]}_${FILE_DATE}${TAR_GZ}
    fi    
done
```

Answer (score 2):

When you reset PATH, the shell can no longer find the executable `rsync`.  When the shell reads the word `rsync`, it looks through the variable named PATH (which it expects to be a colon separated list of directories, not an array) for a file named `rsync`.  Similarly for `tar` and `rm`.  The error messages you see are simply telling you that those commands are not found in your PATH.

Comment: In common case, when you execute a nonexistent command like `raabb`, the Bash complain: "raabb: command not found", but when you reset `PATH`, the Bash complain: "raabb: No such file or directory". Why is there different?

Comment: @zhenguoli That is an interesting point, but I cannot duplicate the error.  In each of bash 4.3.30 and 3.2.57 I get "command not found".

Comment: My Bash version is 4.3.48. Then my output is different. For this question, in normal case, if `rsync` can't find the file, it should complain "/home/tanmay/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/logs: No such file or directory". But not "rsync: No such file or directory". Right answer! +1.